How to manage application.properties in Spring Boot applicaitons
I have a Spring Boot application with an application.properties file. For production I use a separate configuration in a central location, because of this the application.properties only contains config to load this external file:
spring.config.import=/my/prod/application.properties

When developing locally I use development config, so I change the spring.config.import in the application.properties file. The application.properties is managed through git, but I don't want to commit this and having this change open is annoying when committing other changes.
It seems that configuration for different environments can be managed with profiles. Instead of having an application.properties in the resources directory I can have an application-dev.properties and an application-prod.properties. I would like to be able to start the application in prod without having to specify the environment (the application is deployed to an existing Tomcat instance, I wouldn't even know how to specify the environment). This would mean keeping the existing application.properties and adding an application-dev.properties and starting the application with the dev profile. However, the spring.config.import in the dev config doesn't override the config in the application.properties, causing the application to attempt to load the prod config.
How can I better manage my application's config?

You can prefix the import with optional: which will not break the dev one as it now is optional (or override it with that in the application-dev.properties).

Personally, I think that your approach is backwards.  Prod is the only profile that I want to explicitly activate.
